# How to display numbers like 1.1k instead of 1100

Tags: php, wordpress, numeric, display

I am trying to have post views on a website I'm building to display like 1.1k instead of 1000. It's a Wordpress site and I've been having trouble trying to add custom functionality to the website. Every time I added some snippets I've found on here, it crashes the site completely.

Here is the code as it is at the moment - it simply counts the users that land on the post as well as the admin being able to set post counts manually.

```
    if(!function_exists('davenport_getPostViews')):
function davenport_getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = '_davenport_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count == ''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return 0;
    }
    return $count;
}
endif;

if(!function_exists('davenport_setPostViews')):
function davenport_setPostViews() {
    global $post;
    $postID = $post->ID;

    $count_key = '_davenport_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count == '') {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
add_action('davenport_set_post_views', 'davenport_setPostViews');
endif;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm at my whits end trying to figure this one out.

Comment: You can divide by 1000 then add k at the end.

Comment: Sorry can you show me what you mean/where to add that? I'm a noob when it comes to PHP. :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be by dividing it. So doing this would look something like this:

```
<?php 


function DisplayViews($views){
    if($views > 0){
        $display = round($views / 1000, 2);
        return $display."k";
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}


echo DisplayViews($count); //$count should be your view count

?>
```

Although the above would work just fine, I would suggest doing some more checks so that you don't display 0.01k when you only have 10 views. The same goes for when views are above 999,999 views.

To do those checks all you need to do is the following:

```
if($views <= 999){
    //Display number without letter "K"
}

if($views > 999999){
    //Display number with the letter "m"
}
```

So combining those two you can check if the number is less than 100, and also check if it's above 999,999, doing this means you don't display numbers with the wrong letter at the end. Final code will look something like this:

```
<?php

function DisplayViews($views){
    if($views > 0){
        if($views <= 999){
            return $views;
        } elseif($views > 999999){
            $display = round($views / 1000000, 2);
            return $display."M";
        } else {
            $display = round($views / 1000, 2);
            return $display."K";
        }
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}


echo DisplayViews($count);

?>
```

Comment: There is a section that 'displays' the view count, which I'm assuming is where this goes. 

The code is below, do I just replace?

`if(!function_exists('davenport_post_views_display')):
function davenport_post_views_display($custompost = '') {

 global $post;

 if($custompost !== '' ) {
  $post = $custompost;
 }

 $post_views = davenport_getPostViews($post->ID);

 if($post_views < 1) {
     $post_views = 0;
 }

 echo '<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.esc_html($post_views);
}
add_action('davenport_post_views', 'davenport_post_views_display');
endif;`

Answer (score 0):

Call this function on your count variable.

```
function humanize_number($input){
    $input = number_format($input);
    $input_count = substr_count($input, ',');
    if($input_count != '0'){
        if($input_count == '1'){
            return substr($input, 0, -4).'k';
        } else if($input_count == '2'){
            return substr($input, 0, -8).'mil';
        } else if($input_count == '3'){
            return substr($input, 0,  -12).'bil';
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to convert size in bytes to human readable format.

```
function getReadableCount($count, $dec = 2) {
    $units = ['K', 'M', 'B'];
    for ($i = count($units); $i > 0; $i --) {
        $base = pow(1000, $i);
        if ($count >= $base) {
            return round($count/$base, $dec) . $units[$i-1];
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo getReadableCount($count, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view a GitHub post here:https://gist.github.com/bcole808/9371754, they say that you can use

```
function numberAbbreviation($number) {
$abbrevs = array(12 => "T", 9 => "B", 6 => "M", 3 => "K", 0 => "");

foreach($abbrevs as $exponent => $abbrev) {
    if($number >= pow(10, $exponent)) {
        $display_num = $number / pow(10, $exponent);
        $decimals = ($exponent >= 3 && round($display_num) < 100) ? 1 : 0;
        return number_format($display_num,$decimals) . $abbrev;
    }
}
```

}